# Can “How to” be a question?

Tags: grammar, questions

Can I use “How to” instead of “How do I” when I ask a question? And will it be grammatical?

I often notice some English learners use “How to” when they ask a question.

Comment: Hmm, *how (best) to answer this*? :)

Answer (score 8):

The usage of **how to** to ask a question is a direct translation from the learner's own language: it is not correct as a question in English. The expression is used in titles, for example ["How to win friends and influence people"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People)

In English, a how-question is formed by taking a normal sentence, making a question in the usual way (by applying [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/question-forms-subjectobject-questions)) and then adding **how** in front of it.

> I get a visa 
>   I **do** get a visa - *add **do** because there is no auxiliary verb* 
>   Do I get a visa? - *invert subject and auxiliary*
>   How do I get a visa? - *add **how***

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking of asking some guy `How do I kill an insect ?`, versus `How to kill an insect ?` ? If so, I believe the latter is not grammatically correct.
  I think `How to` is used more in titles and such (not in the question form), for example: `How to kill all the insects in your house in less than 3 hours`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking the question directly to a person or group of people then

> How do I feed a lion?

is grammatical. However we can also be making the point that it's a problem to do a task and say

> Ah, but how to feed the lion? That's the question.

Here we are not explicitly asking a specific person for an answer, though in conversation we are open to receiving answers.

I suspect that these two cases are sometimes confused by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "How to play tennis" is noun phrase. It does not contain a finite verb and is not a complete sentence. It is not a question. It means "the method of playing tennis"

Noun phrases are useful: They can be used, for example, as headings in a piece of writing. They are building blocks of complete sentences

> He taught me how to play tennis.

This is a complete sentence with a subject, verb and two objects. It is not a question.

"How" can also be used in questions, but it needs the inverted verb to be a question.

> How does he play tennis?

Answer (score 4):

In English, whether something is a question or a statement can depend on its context or delivery.

For example:

1. *Salesman:* Hey, have I got a deal for you!
2. *Customer:* Really?
3. *Salesman:* Really!

Sentence 1 is worded in the form of a question ("Have I"), but the intent is to make a statement. Sentences 2 and 3 contain the same text, but #2 is a question while #3 is a statement.

"How to" can be used in a question, particularly when someone is asking a question of themselves (e.g. "How to win?"), but its natural function is to cue a reader to expect a heading or title (e.g. *How to cook a potato*).