# Is "where to buy" grammatical?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

When I want to buy a book, can I say "where to buy this book"? I just tried to search "where to buy" on google, there were a lot of search results. But I feel it doesn't look right. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can “How to” be a question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162104/can-how-to-be-a-question)

Comment: By the way, _Grammarly_ is a made-up word that is the name of a piece of software. It may at some time become a word in general use, but at present, the word you want is _grammatically_

Comment: It is common to use the form of embedded questions (without inversion) as titles and headlines. _People ask us where to buy X_ -> _Where to buy X?_ as the title of an article. That is probably why you found so many hits.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks. Do you usually say "grammatically right"? Or "grammatically correct"?

Comment: @FrankMi: I usually say "grammatical".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse questions

> Where do I buy this book?

With phrases that are not full sentences, such as "where to buy this book". That phrase means "the place that sells this book".  You can use it as:

> Please tell me where to buy this book.

The question would be better phrased as

> Where can I buy this book?