# How to use "How to" and "What to"?

Tags: questions

Is "how to" in these context(questions) correct?

> 1. How to go to {somewhere}?
> 2. How do you/I go {somewhere}?
> 3. How to get {something}?
> 4. How do you/I get {something}?

And what about "what to"

> 1. What to do in {some certain situation}?
> 2. What do you/I do in {some certain situation}?
> 3. What to do?
> 4. What do I do?

Are these correct or not.

Could help me with how to use "How to" and "What to" and the rule behind these, please.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162104/can-how-to-be-a-question

Answer (score -1):

> 1. How to go to England? (*when you know the name of a certain place and use it for the first time in a conversation,  not necessarily first mention needed though*)
> 2. How to go there? (*when you have previously mentioned about the place, use a pronoun to refer it.*)

> 1. How did y'all/you all go to England?
> 2. How did y'all/you all go there?

> How to get {something/that thing}? (*usage is correct*)

> 1. How will you get that thing? (*indicating future action*)
> 2. How did y'all/you all get that thing? (*indicating past action*)
> 3. How do you get that thing? (*indicating present action*)

---

> What to do in {some certain situation}? (*correct usage*)

> 1. What do y'all/you all do in {certain situation}? (*correct usage - indicates present time*)

- **Alternatives**

> 2. What will y'all/you all do in {certain situation}? (*correct usage - indicates future time*)
> 3. What did y'all/you all do in that situation? (*correct usage - indicates past time*)

> What to do? (*this sounds like a title, a rhetorical question, or a line of a song, but the usage is correct*)

> What do I do? (*correct usage*)

Comment: _How did you'll_ is definitely wrong! Anyway, the OP didn't ask about the past tense. _How to..._ is not a standard way of asking a question, although in some contexts it could be an implied question - see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Oh my my, it is not the correct abbreviation that I used. Let me edit it. I shouldn't have used abbreviations in the first place. Thanks @KateBunting

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I did check that link. But it is very natural way of questioning, isn't it? I have heard a lot of _How to_ questions in my life. Is that completely wrong?

Comment: It isn't natural in my (British) English - certainly not as a direct question in ordinary conversation.

Comment: Thank you very much @DhanishthaGhosh and @ KateBunting for the answer and the link. But according to the answers to the question in that link, "how to" in a question usage is not correct. Would anyone shed some more light? Thank you.

Comment: It is not correct as a standard way of asking a question, so for all practical purposes you can forget about it. You _can_ ask "Could you please tell me how to get to [somewhere]?" "Can you tell me what to do?" etc.